# Power BI Measure in Table - BLANK to 0 Issue

Tags: powerbi, ssas, dax, measure

I have the below measure I use in my Power BI report.

```
Sighting Count:=COUNTROWS('Fact Sighting Latest')
```

It does work on my card and when I add it to my table in Power BI report.

Problem is: When there are no records my card shows a value of (BLANK) and I want to replace it with a 0.

So I go and I change my measure to the below.

```
Sighting Count:=IF(ISBLANK(COUNTROWS('Fact Sighting Latest')),0, COUNTROWS('Fact Sighting Latest'))
```

It works on the card, but then nothing renders on my table.

Below also works on the card, but NOT when it's added to a table in the report.

```
Sighting Count:=COUNTROWS('Fact Sighting Latest')+0
```

Anyone know what is going on?

Comment: when you say "works on the card, but NOT when it's added to a table in the report", what's the result? what does the table show?

Comment: It just loads and loads and then eventually times out. If I remove it from the table it renders straight away.

Comment: might be a problem with the data model; not enough information to tell. Post your data model diagram, images of the report table; a data sample to reproduce the problem would be great. This kind of problems can't be fixed blindly.